# Meijer G-function limit for $z\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions

I am trying to understand if the integral $$f(R)=\int_a^R\frac{K_1(r)dr}{r}$$
has a finite limit for $R\rightarrow\infty$.

With Wolfram Mathematica I got the following primitive:

$$\frac{1}{4} G_{1,3}^{2,1}\left(\frac{r}{2},\frac{1}{2}|
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 -\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

but I can't get the limit for $r\rightarrow\infty$. If I plot it, it seems to go to me value around $-1.57$ but, again, Mathematica does not seem to handle these Meijer G-functions very well and after $r\sim 30$ it blows up to infinity.

Of course, the first derivative of this function is:

$$f^\prime(R)=\frac{K_1(R)}{R}$$

which goes to zero for $R\rightarrow\infty$. But this does not give me the constant to which it tends.

Any ideas or reference?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the value of the constant (finite limit) should be
$$
\int_1^\infty dt \frac{e^{-a t}\sqrt{t^2-1}}{t}\ .
$$
[checked with Mathematica for a few values]
You can just use the integral representation
$$
K_1(r)=r \int_1^\infty e^{-rt}\sqrt{t^2-1}dt
$$
and swap the integrals. The integral in $r$ is easy 
$$
\int_a^R dr e^{-r t}=\frac{e^{-a t}-e^{-R t}}{t}
$$
and the surviving integral in $t$ has a dependence in $R$ that can be easily evaluated.

Comment: Isn't the answer good enough?